# table-layout does not compile (syntax errors)

Tags: java, libgdx

I have code:

```
public class Menu 
{

    private Skin skin;
    Label nameLabel = new Label("Name:", skin);
    TextField nameText = new TextField(null, skin);
    Label addressLabel = new Label("Address:", skin);
    TextField addressText = new TextField(null, skin);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.add(nameLabel);
    table.add(nameText).width(100);
    table.row();
    table.add(addressLabel);
    table.add(addressText).width(100);
}
```

and I have problem with adding:

> - Syntax error on token "nameLabel", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
> - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

and

> - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
> - Syntax error on token "add", = expected after this token

and

> - Syntax error on token "row", Identifier expected after this token

and

> - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
> - Syntax error on token "addressLabel", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

and

> - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
> - Syntax error on token "add", = expected after this token

I use this tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/p/table-layout/).
What I doing wrong?

Comment: @Juned Ahsan It's so simple... Thenks you.

Comment: If you found Juned Ahsan's answer correct you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are writing executable statements outisde of a `method/constructor/block`. In java you cannot write the executable statements directly in class. You need to move the following statements in a `method`:

```
table.add(nameLabel);
table.add(nameText).width(100);
table.row();
table.add(addressLabel);
table.add(addressText).width(100);
```